# Join cell with two values in SQL?

Tags: postgresql, join, dynamic

Working in postgresQL, I have a code value column where there are two values within one cell:

```
CREATE TABLE test.table1(Site varchar(50), CodeValue1 varchar(50));
INSERT INTO test.table1
VALUES ('A', '1005'),
       ('B', '1006|1007'),
       ('C', '1008');
```

I want to join the code value column to a second table, like:

```
CREATE TABLE test.table2(Note varchar(50), CodeValue2 varchar(50));
INSERT INTO test.table2
VALUES ('Note1','1005'),
       ('Note2', '1006'), 
       ('Note3', '1007');


--this does not work:
select * from test.table1
left join test.table2 on table2.CodeValue2 = table1.Codevalue1
```

Is there a way to query the '1006|1007' so the join works for either 1006 or 1007 without splitting table 1 into more rows. My desired output would be this:

| Site | Note | Code Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Note 1 | 1005 |
| B | Note 2 | 1006 |
| B | Note 3 | 1007 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best approach I have so far, using a subquery, I think this will work fine for my needs but keen to hear if there are other solutions:

```
select * from (
select Site
, unnest(string_to_array(CodeValue1, '|')) as CV
from  test.table1) t1
left join (select * from test.table2) t2 on t2.CodeValue2 = t1.CV);
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing a delimited string (`table1.codevalue1`) is an extremely bad idea, it will cause the same type of issues on virtually every query written against it. A much better approach would be to normalize your data and store each value as a separate row. But as to your direct question can it be written *without splitting table1 into more rows* - well yes it can:

```
select t1.site, t2.note, t2.codevalue2 
  from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 
    on ( position ('|' || t2.codevalue2 || '|'  in '|' || t1.codevalue1 || '|') > 0 );
```

But I certainly would not want work with that `on` condition, and variants of it.

Your latest attempt (as your answer) is close. It fails because the `outer join` results in the row ('c', 1008, null, null) also being returned. You can correct that by doing an `inner join`. Finally, you can reduce to a much simpler version by eliminating your outer most `select * from (...`. That format is very seldom necessary. Just:

```
select t1.site, t2.note, t2.codevalue2
  from table2 t2
  join (select site, string_to_table(codevalue1, '|') cv from table1) t1
    on t1.cv = t2.codevalue2;
```

Note, `string_to_table(...)` function instead of `unnest(string_to_array(...))` functions.

See [demo for all here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=999d79df46438174bc0908e189317b9d).